# Is it possible to configure Saxon to return variable value and error line

Tags: xslt, saxon

Running towards a testbench that I do not have access to configure, I get the following error.

```
While processing file file:///Xxx, an exception of type net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException occurs. Exception message is If the format attribute is present, the {value} property MUST be valid in accordance with the {format input type} property.
```

I wonder if its possible to configure Saxon software so it returns the value instead of just showing the text string "{value}". Also, is it possible to configure Saxon to return
some estimation of where the error is (line)?

I already asked the service provider of the testbench and they just state that they just forward what the software (Saxon) returns.
I currently do not have the information of Saxon version they run.

It's rather cumbersome to look for error and solve them only by having above error. The consequences is that I have to comment-out blocks of code until I find the faulty error which takes unnecessary time.

I do of course understand the area of problem in terms of the relation between the element value and it's defined attribute value and that there is a mismatch there.

Comment: Do you get line number information when running Saxon from the command line?

Comment: Yes, from terminal and in my local environment, I can intentionally produce an error adding some faults in code: "Error on line 471 column 7 of page-2.xsl", it's not always exact but it narrows down the faulty error. This error is when I build the XHTML document. The question above is in relation to when I send the produced XHTML document to the suppliers testbench (where no error where visible in local XSLT environment).

Comment: I guess the code of the testbench needs to be configured to set up Saxon to report full information but it will be a lot of guessing if we don't know the exact code they currently have and no knowledge about the Saxon version and API they use. https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/repository/he/revisions/master/entry/latest10/samples/java/he/S9APIExamples.java#L645 is one example

Comment: It's a fair answer. I think yo can just move your comment to an answer and I will accept it. Seems I would have to convince the service provider for the test bench to configure their test bench, which I assume they would be reluctant to do due to dev costs.

Comment: The odd thing about this is, it doesn't look like a Saxon error message. I've no idea where it might be coming from. Displaying the stack trace associated with the exception would be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the exception is an instance of `net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException`, which is a Saxon exception class, the message `If the format attribute is present, the {value} property MUST be valid in accordance with the {format input type} property.`  is not a Saxon error message. There is nothing, of course, to stop other software using the Saxon exception class for its own purposes.

Furthermore, it looks as if the message associated with the exception has been wrapped in some further text `While processing file file:///Xxx, an exception of type...` which also does not come from Saxon.

To discover how to improve the diagnostics here, you'll need to find out (a) where the exception originates (a stack trace would be useful), and (b) what software is catching the and displaying it, and whether that software can be customised.

The answer to the question "Is it possible to configure Saxon to...", as far as this particular error is concerned, is therefore: probably not. There's no evidence that Saxon is involved in either the detection or the reporting of this error.